# Prompt for password when using smbnetfs

Tags: mount, passwords, samba

I'm using Ubuntu Focal and I'd like to mount some samba shares.

If I use `mount -t cifs` and don't provide a password, then it's going to prompt me to input one. However `mount` can be only used as a `root` user, and on some environments I'm unable to switch to the root user.

So I thought I'd use `smbnetfs` and it works as intended. However with `smbnetfs` I have to store my password in a plain text file, which I'm not comfortable doing. Even with file permissions set to `600`, I'm still worried that other users on the same system with root privileges can potentially read the configuration file.

Is there a way to make `smbnetfs` ask for a password when running `smbnetfs ~/network`, or to store the password in an encrypted way? Or maybe there's some other tool with this functionality which is also accessible for non root users?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44318) I've come to the solution to use gio:

In case anyone stumbles upon this ticket in the future, the following has worked for me:

```
#Installation on Ubuntu Focal
apt-get install -y gvfs-bin gvfs-backends gvfs-fuse

export $(dbus-launch)
gio mount smb://<domain>\;<user>@<host>/<folder>
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /mnt/smb # where /mnt/smb is any path where you'd like to access the samba share from
```

Now the share is going to be visible for all applications under `/mnt/smb`.